# Has-a relationships and signals in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I'm new to development with Qt and our design uses the has-a relationship in a couple of places. In some of these cases the container should expose the signal of the internal object, and then I've currently written a private slot for each such signal, where I in practice re-emit the signal again.  Is there some short-cut available in Qt that aids in exposing the signal of the internal object on the container?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to create a slot for reemiting the signal, you could connect a signal with another signal. This way you will avoid the slot definition.

So in your container you would have something like this:

```
connect(object, SIGNAL(signal1()), this, SIGNAL(signal1()));
```

Of course you have to redefine the signal on your container.

For more details check the [signal slot documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/signalsandslots.html)

Answer (score 5):

From the [documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/signalsandslots.html):

> You can connect as many signals as you want to a single slot, and a signal can be connected to as many slots as you need. It is even possible to connect a signal directly to another signal. (This will emit the second signal immediately whenever the first is emitted.)

The following is legal:

```
connect(sender, SIGNAL(originalSignal()), SIGNAL(newSignal()));
```

Answer (score 0):

The re-emitting of Signals also allows re-emitting multiple signals.

testclass.h:

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>

class TestClass : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit TestClass(QObject *parent = 0)
    {
        connect(this, SIGNAL(signal1()), this, SIGNAL(signal2()));
        connect(this, SIGNAL(signal1()), this, SIGNAL(signal2()));
        connect(this, SIGNAL(signal2()), this, SLOT(slot()));
    }
    void emitSignal1()
    {
        emit signal1();
    }

signals:
    void signal1();
    void signal2();

public slots:
    void slot()
    {
        qDebug() << "SLOT HAS BEEN CALLED";
    }
};
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include "testclass.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    TestClass instance;

    instance.emitSignal1();

    return a.exec();
}
```

The result is that the slot is called twice in this case.

Answer (score -1):

If it is internal structure of your class, why won't you make it friend class. Then you can inside your internal structure call directly `emit parentObj->signal()`